# Symfony2 Confirmation when going to url

Tags: php, symfony, events, controller, routes

I'm working on some sort of "ChargeUserForActionBundle".
Because user need to know that he will be charged for accessing concrete URL, I need to create a some sort of "confirmation page". 
Overall flow should look like this:

- From action A, go to action B.
- Pause execution of action B.
- Ask for confirmation in event listener. If user disagree - stop executing action B. Else:
- Continue with action B

How can I achieve something like this?

EDIT:

```
public function paidLinkAction(){
    //Call event which trigger charging fee procedure. Inside this event we will inform user that he will be charged
    $this->get('yasecure_billing.app.charging')->callChargeEvent($user, 'Example action');
    /*
     * if user agree, come back here, and do rest of stuff
     */
}
```

What I should implement to allow my listener to come back to paidLinkAction after asking for confirmation? And how to tell paidLinkAction that user is already charged? 
Of course implementation should be h4x-proof. We cannot have situation when user can fool application that he was charged already(so cookies are bad idea). I was thinking about session?

Comment: The easiest way would be with javascript. Create a dialog popup, ask for confirmation and in affirmative case, submit the form B via JS.

Comment: I thought about this, but i need to make it "scalable" - there can be a lot of links, and it would be awful to remember about including JS to every link.
In the last resort, I can create twig function to render links with this script. But i would like to avoid this.

Comment: it's will be not very userfriendly ! but you can use services with kernel dependencies : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: Javascript is definately not the way to go. User can come back later and ask for refund claiming he had javascript disabled.

Comment: My solution don't speak about Javascript but Services & Kernel (from Symfony) ;)

Comment: What exactly do you need to pause? I think your idea is good, have you implemented it? You can create a simple page with 2 buttons in order to confirm or cancel anything.

Comment: I've added some code to my question. Maybe it would clear what I want to achieve. 
A.L - I want to do it like that, but I don't know how to implement it, and make it safe. 
And we should have in mind this, that users can get to paid content by direct link...

Comment: I've an idea:
Maybe i should make something like "agreeAction", which will ask for two arguments - first, string, for action which we want to charge(e.g "AcmeArticleBundle:ExclusiveContent:hotArticles"), and second one will be array with arguments which  hotArticlesAction needs to work?
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bundle we made or even just inspire yourself from it.
It's called [AvAlertifyBundle](https://github.com/AppVentus/AvAlertifyBundle) and it allows you to manage alerts of any kind (success, info, warning and what will be interesting for you ... CONFIRM modal).

You can get more information about confirm modals [here](https://github.com/AppVentus/AvAlertifyBundle/blob/master/README_Confirm.md) or you can go to the base documentation [here](https://github.com/AppVentus/AvAlertifyBundle).

In some words, you'll just have to add something like this :

```
<a href="/your_url" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger confirm" data-title="Are you sure ?" data-body="You'll have to pay something ! Do you understand ?" data-cancel-button-class="cancel" data-confirm-button-class="danger">
    Pay actions
</a>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Nice bundle. I think I will make use of it in future, but not in this problem :( Using any JS solution is too risky.